# can't connect to mysql in Opensuse 10.2

Tags: mysql, opensuse, mysql-error-2002

I have problem with mysql  I've installed the mysql in YAST but when in console I type this one:

```
mysql -u root
```

it tells me:

```
Error 2002: Can't connect to local mysql server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Comment: Ensure that mysql daemon is running.

Comment: how? I am newbie in suse

Comment: Sorry, but you're a newbie in using search engines, too? Using php-coders answer as search term will give you all the information you need.

Comment: @negin http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:MySQL_installation

Comment: YES! it works:D I LOVE YOU!!!!

Comment: @Negin I've just posted my comment as answer, so you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from OpenSuSe wiki (http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:MySQL_installation):

> After the installation of MySQL, it is only installed but it is not running. To make it run, the so called daemon for MySQL (mysqld) must be running. mysqld can be started manually by calling
>
> # rcmysql start
>
> with root privileges. You can check whether it is running by using
>
> # rcmysql status

Also this will be usefull for you:

> Another option is to start the daemon is during the boot.
>
> Go to YaST -> System -> System Services (Runlevel). Wait a few seconds before YaST has examined all the Runlevels. Then select mysqld and press the enable button.
>
> Alternatively, you can enable MySQL startup at boot time by issuing
>
> # insserv rcmysql